# Numpy Matplotlib Install on Fedora Linux

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am running Fedora Linux/RHEL on Oracle VirtualBox on my Windows 7 machine and trying to install matplotlib-1.3.1 on VM.
I have numpy-1.6.1, scipy-0.13.0 as well as python-2.6.6.

Both Numpy and Scipy are built from source i.e. downloaded the tar.gz file, extracted and then ran build and install from the extracted folders. I have also checked the installed versions from python shell.

However, whenever I am trying to build matplotlib-1.3.1 from source, it is giving me the below screen.

Below is the screen when building matplotlib from source:

```
~]$ python setup.py build
============================================================================
Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
        matplotlib: yes [1.3.1]
            python: yes [2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 10 2013, 22:48:45)  [GCC
                    4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)]]
          platform: yes [linux2]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
             numpy: yes [version 1.6.1]
          dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.1]
           tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                    WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                    install it after matplotlib.]
         pyparsing: yes [pyparsing was not found. It is required for
                    mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                    install it after matplotlib.]
             pycxx: yes [Couldn't import.  Using local copy.]
            libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                    be found. Using local copy.]
          freetype: no  [pkg-config information for 'freetype2' could
                    not be found.]
               png: yes [version 1.2.49]

OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
       sample_data: yes [installing]
          toolkits: yes [installing]
             tests: yes [using nose version 1.3.0]

OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
            macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
            qt4agg: no  [PyQt4 not found]
           gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
         gtk3cairo: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
            gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
             tkagg: no  [TKAgg requires Tkinter.]
             wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
               gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
               agg: yes [installing]
             cairo: yes [installing, version 1.8.6]
         windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]

OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
            dvipng: no
       ghostscript: yes [version 8.70]
             latex: no
           pdftops: no

============================================================================
                    * The following required packages can not be built:
                    * freetype
```

I tried building dependencies for matplotlib as mentioned in [Matplotlib install page](http://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html#how-to-install) but I get message "No source rpm found" as shown below:

```
~]$ su -c "yum-builddep python-matplotlib"
Password:
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* HDP-epel: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
* base: mirror.dattobackup.com
* epel: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
* extras: centos.aol.com
* updates: mirror.cogentco.com
59 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Checking for new repos for mirrors
Enabling epel-source repository
epel-source/metalink                                                 |  14 kB     00:00
epel-source                                                          | 3.3 kB     00:00
http://mirror.umd.edu/fedora/epel/6/SRPMS/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xm does not match metalink for epel-source
Trying other mirror.
epel-source                                                          | 3.5 kB     00:00
epel-source/primary_db                                               | 1.6 MB     00:01
9 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No source RPM found for python-matplotlib-0.99.1.2-1.el6.x86_64
No uninstalled build requires
```

Just to note that I have successfully built from source nose-1.3.0, ipython-1.1.0, sympy-0.7.3, pandas-0.11.0 as dependencies before installing matplotlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above problem is solved. It's because the required freetype package could not be found.

Interested readers may go to the link

[Freetype-2.5.0 Install](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/freetype2.html)

and follow the steps to get freetype installed. Please note that after extracting the bz2 file, have to go into the folder to run the ./configure and make. For installing the doc, need to login as root user and follow the command as mentioned. Hope this helps.

NOTE: The above error that I have been getting is resolved but there is a new error that of ftheader.h not found is raised. I have opened a separate thread for that. Here is the link

[Install error: ftheader.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697457/numpy-matplotlib-install-error-ftheader-h-no-such-file-or-directory)